# write a script to automatically run through my registration page react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a script that actually goes through and enters all the fields on my registration form, and then hit register. I want this to happen every few minutes, and then I will delete them right after they do it. This is my attempt to get around cold start firebase invocations.

Here's my registration page. I am fairly new to this, so i'm not sure where to start or how to do this. btw, it's react

```
let firestore = firebase.firestore()

const FormItem = Form.Item


var userIDStripeSubmit = ""
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) return
      const email = this.props.form.getFieldValue('email')
      const passwordOne = this.props.form.getFieldValue('password1')
      const firstName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('First Name')
      const lastName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Last Name')
      const companyName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Company Name')

      const {
        history,
      } = this.props

      AuthorizationHome.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
        .then((authUser) => facades.userFacade().doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, email))

        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({'error': error})
        })



        // adding into profiledata collection


            // var userID = ""
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if(user) {
                
                console.log(user.uid)
                userIDStripeSubmit = user.uid

                  console.log("userid inside firebase auth is" + user.uid)

                        //  var firstNameFromField = 
                          firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
                            firstname: firstName,
                            lastname: lastName,
                            companyname: companyName,
                            accountStatus: "inactive",
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            alert(error.message);
                        });
                        createCheckoutSession(user.uid)
              }
              })
             
              // firestore collection query
                
    })
  }

  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
  }

  compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password1')) {
      callback('Passwords do not match!');
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['password2'], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  }


  

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form
    const { error } = this.state
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  hideRequiredMark={true} className="registration-form" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
        { error && <Alert type="error" message={error.message}/> }

      
       
        <FormItem label="Email" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'Invalid email address',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your email address',
            }],
          })(
            <Input placeholder="Enter email" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        

{/*  */}

        <FormItem label="First Name" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('First Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your First Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Last Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Last Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Last Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem label="Company Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Company Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Company Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password1', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please choose a password',
            }, {
              validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem label="Confirm Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password2', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password',
            }, {
              validator: this.compareToFirstPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur} placeholder="Confirm password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" id="submitButton">Register</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegistrationForm);
export default withRouter(WrappedRegistrationForm)
```

Comment: Hey Roger, this is something you would want to do on the backend using a cronjob or scheduled function.

Comment: @Omar hey! I appreciate the response. I tried with CronJob, it renders my registration page, and I set it to go to the stripe checkout page with a userid and everything, but still happening. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to access your page, input the values that you want to and submit the form. Puppeteer is headless by default, which means that it runs on the terminal without need to open a browser.

Place ID's on your inputs and in your button, to allow puppeteer to find your input/button. With email, you will automate typing with:

```
await page.type("#email", "email");
```

Install puppeteer on your project:

```
npm install puppeteer --save
```

The code to automate your page form submission with puppeteer will be like:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    
async function submitForm() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://yourpage.com", { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  await page.type("#email", "email"); //First arg : ID of your input; Second arg the value that you want to input
  await page.type("#firstName", "firstName");
  await page.type("#lastName", "lastName");
  await page.type("#companyName", "companyName");
  // You could here on the value argument,
  // if you have security concerns, use environment variables with process.env
  await page.type("#password", "******");
  await page.type("#confirmPassword", "******");

  await page.click("#submit");
  await browser.close();
}
```

After that, you could place this logic to run on CronJob using a library like [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron).

Install it on your project:

```
npm install cron --save
```

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;

async function submitForm() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://yourpage.com", { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  await page.type("#email", "email"); //First arg : ID of your input; Second arg the value that you want to input
  await page.type("#firstName", "firstName");
  await page.type("#lastName", "lastName");
  await page.type("#companyName", "companyName");
  // You could here on the value argument,
  // if you have security concerns, use environment variables with process.env
  await page.type("#password", "******");
  await page.type("#confirmPassword", "******");

  await page.click("#submit");
  await browser.close();
}

var job = new CronJob(
  "* */1 * * * *", //every one minute
  function () {
    console.log("Trying to submit my form!");
    submitForm();
    console.log("Form submitted!");
  },
  null,
  true,
  "America/Los_Angeles"
);

job.start();
```

When you execute this code on your server using Node.js, at every one minute your application form will be submitted.